# Connecting my Roll Up Piano via USB to record MIDI

Tags: macos, usb, garageband, midi

I have a roll up piano (see the image) that has an USB output.

> [image]

An USB cable comes with it: it is able to connect the roll up piano with the computer.

> [image]

I have connected it to my macbook.

What are the steps to record MIDI on OSX using the roll up piano and the USB cable?

Relevant output:

```
❯ ioreg -p IOUSB
+-o Root  <class IORegistryEntry, id 0x100000100, retain 14>
  +-o Root Hub Simulation Simulation@14000000  <class AppleUSBRootHubDevice, id 0x100000322, registered, matched, active, busy 0 (2 ms), retain 8>
    +-o BRCM20702 Hub@14300000  <class AppleUSBDevice, id 0x100000dcd, registered, matched, active, busy 0 (2 ms), retain 12>
    | +-o Bluetooth USB Host Controller@14330000  <class AppleUSBDevice, id 0x100000e25, registered, matched, active, busy 0 (2224 ms), retain 17>
    +-o USB MIDI Interface @14100000  <class AppleUSBDevice, id 0x1000016a9, registered, matched, active, busy 0 (14 ms), retain 20>
```

I would like to use GarageBand or so to record it, but for some reason, there is no data coming from my piano.

However, it is detected by the software:

[image]

Is there any low-level way to test if the the machine gets data from the piano (e.g. a terminal command etc)? How to fix this problem? Should I install any drivers?

Comment: What software is detecting the keyboard, GarageBand? Have you tried to set up the device using /Applications/Utilities/Audio MIDI Setup?

Comment: Why are you mentioning Ubuntu? Are you running it on your MacBook?

Comment: @IconDaemon Yes. Yes, I tried Audio MIDI Setup, and my device is listed there. I'm not sure how I can check if it's receiving data from the piano.

Comment: @CL. Whoups, that was a mistake. I'm running Ubuntu on another machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>In the Ubuntu terminal, you can use `amidi` or `aseqdump` to monitor MIDI messages.</strike>

OS X has no command-line tool to monitor MIDI messages.
You have to [use](https://www.native-instruments.com/en/support/knowledge-base/show/998/how-to-monitor-the-input-of-a-midi-controller/) some graphical tool like [MIDI Monitor](https://www.snoize.com/MIDIMonitor/) or [MIDI-OX](http://www.midiox.com/).
You can also test it in the Audio/MIDI Setup windows with the "Test Setup" button; when you are playing something, the port icon (the triangle) should turn red.

To record MIDI data, use any MIDI sequencer. There is no reason why GarageBand should not work, but you could try [Ardour](https://ardour.org/) instead.

Comment: I guess my Roll Up Piano itself is kinda broken since it doesn't work on Ubuntu as well. My digital piano works fine. Thanks!